# Windows (MSYS2) built OpenOCD fails to create sockets

Tags: build, configure, openocd

I've cloned openOCD from https://github.com/gnu-mcu-eclipse/openocd
and built it using MSYS2 (MINGW32) shell. Build passed without any trouble and when tried to execute, it failed and gave error "Error: error creating socket".

I enabled debugging option and found it is coming from server.c file.
I'm using 64 bit Windows 10 PC for building.

Error is coming from below code segment,

```
    c->fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (c->fd == -1) {
        LOG_ERROR("error creating socket: %s", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
```

I noticed that a macro which has to be enabled for WIN32 build has not gotten enabled, which if enabled calls windows specific socket functions.

```
int server_preinit(void)
{
/* this currently only calls WSAStartup on native win32 systems
 * before any socket operations are performed.
 * This is an issue if you call init in your config script */

#ifdef _WIN32
WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;

wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

if (WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) != 0) {
    LOG_ERROR("Failed to Open Winsock");
    exit(-1);
}

/* register ctrl-c handler */
SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ControlHandler, TRUE);

signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler);
signal(SIGBREAK, sig_handler);
signal(SIGABRT, sig_handler);
#endif

return ERROR_OK;
}
```

I manually enabled this macro, and compilation failed.

Can anyone help to identify if I missed something in configuring openOCD?
I'm invoking configure script by "--disable-werror" option alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build OpenOCD with MinGW compiler, not MSYS one. You can try to use script from [this repo](https://github.com/kekyo/OpenOCDonMinGW).
Also the link has description how to install MinGW under MSYS.